# Deleted eclipsec.exe back in installation folder of Eclipse RCP application after p2 update

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have an Eclipse RCP application that could be updated via a p2 repository.
In the p2.inf file is defined that the eclipsec.exe is copied to a file with another name and after that it is deleted.

```
units.0.instructions.configure=\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/readme);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.copy(source:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe,target:${installFolder}/XXX.exe,overwrite:true);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/eclipsec.exe);\    
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/notice.html);\     
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/epl-v10.html);\
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.remove(path:${installFolder}/.eclipseproduct);
```

When the built application is **unzipped/installed**, it is visible that **eclipsec.exe** is correctly renamed to what was expected. After an update via p2 repository it is restored in the installation directory.

Any ideas how to stop it from reappearing after an update?

If it matters, the application is built with Maven Tycho.